# Why the case when doesn't work in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like the below showed.

```
 select * from tbl a
    WHERE    a.device_cat =
                     (CASE (SELECT   :VIEW1
                              FROM   DUAL
                             WHERE   :VIEW1 IN
                                           (SELECT   DISTINCT version
                                              FROM   tbl2))
                         WHEN NULL
                         THEN
                            NULL
                         ELSE
                            DECODE (:device_cat, 'ALL', a.device_cat, :device_cat)
                      END)
```

So, when the below query is null, a.device_cat should be null, if so, the above query will always return empty records. But, the records are definitely exists when a.device_cat is null. Please help me! Thanks!

```
 (SELECT   :VIEW1
                                  FROM   DUAL
                                 WHERE   :VIEW1 IN
                                               (SELECT   DISTINCT version
                                                  FROM   tbl2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare to null like this:

```
   a.device_cat =null
```

Try this:

```
select * from tbl a
     WHERE    nvl(a.device_cat, 0) =
                 nvl((CASE (SELECT   :VIEW1
                          FROM   DUAL
                         WHERE   :VIEW1 IN
                                       (SELECT   DISTINCT version
                                          FROM   tbl2))
                     WHEN null
                     THEN
                        null
                     ELSE
                        DECODE (:device_cat, 'ALL', a.device_cat, :device_cat)
                  END), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare `null` to `null` like that.

It is like:

```
undefined = undefined
```

Which is not true... Something you don't know isn't something you don't know. At least, in SQL.

You can use `coalesce` to circumvent this:

```
WHERE    coalesce(a.device_cat, '###') =
                 (CASE (SELECT   coalesce(:VIEW1, '###')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WHEN NULL` case will never be reached, because in SQL `NULL`s are not equal to each other.

Switching to the other `CASE` syntax should work, though:

```
CASE
    WHEN (
       SELECT :VIEW1 FROM DUAL WHERE :VIEW1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT version FROM tbl2)
    ) IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE DECODE (:device_cat, 'ALL', a.device_cat, :device_cat)
END
```

This expression uses `IS NULL` operator instead of the comparison, providing the desired behavior.